# if request.method=="POST": is not working for edit function

Tags: django

I am able to load my instance with all my field populated but when I click submit, the edits doesn't save. Infact but adding print statements in my function, the code doesn't load beyond the if request.method=="POST":(refer to traceback).

#### traceback

```
[04/Feb/2019 15:38:30] "GET /testimonypost/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8081 Not Found: /testimonypost/.jpg
[04/Feb/2019 15:38:30] "GET /testimonypost/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17479 a [04/Feb/2019 15:38:35] "GET /40/testimony/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 5321 Not Found: /40/testimony/.jpg
[04/Feb/2019 15:38:35] "GET /40/testimony/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17476
[04/Feb/2019 15:38:56] "POST /40/testimony/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4224 Not Found: /40/testimony/.jpg
[04/Feb/2019 15:38:56] "GET /40/testimony/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17476
```

#### template

link to the form

```
<a href="{% url 'testimonyedit' objects.id %}">edit</a>
```

template form

```
<form class="form-group" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{%csrf_token%}
{%for field in form%}



    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <span class="text-danger small">{{field.errors}}</span>
    </div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2"{{field.label_tag}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>



{%endfor%}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/testimony/edit', views.TestimonyUpdate, name='testimonyedit'),
]
```

#### views.py

```
@login_required
def TestimonyUpdate(request, id=None):
    instance=get_object_or_404(Testimony, id=id, user=request.user)
    if instance.user == request.user:
        form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        print('a')
        if request.method == "POST":
            print('4')
            if form.is_valid():
                form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
                print('3')
                instance=form.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()
                context={
                    "instance":instance
                }

                return render(request, 'details.html', context)
        return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})

    else:
        return HttpResponse('You are unauthorized to edit this post')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some wrong assumptions and your code has some flaws in updating instance. Lets address them one by one:

First, When you are hitting submit button, its making a [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request. So then the lines after `request.method == "POST"` will be executed.

Second, When the form validation fails, or you are making a [get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request(just hitting the address with url), it will not execute the codes after `request.method == "POST"`.

Third, And the instance is not updating because, you need to pass the instance in `TestimonyForm` inside `if request.method=='POST'` code block, like this:

```
form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if form.is_valid():
    instance=form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
```

Finally, I would refactor your code like this:

```
def update_testimony(request, id=None):  # used snake case for method name. Please see PEP8 style guide regarding naming. 
    instance=get_object_or_404(Testimony, id=id, user=request.user). # getting  Testimony object
    form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance). # initiating TestimonyForm form
    if request.method == "POST":  # checking request type
        if form.is_valid():     # checking if form is valid
           instance=form.save()  # saving the form to update the instance
           context={
              "instance":instance
           }
           return render(request, 'details.html', context)

     return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form}). # returning form for get request
```

Comment: Hi ruddra, I just added my form template. I am not sure how your answer relates to my form method. i also applied your changes to my code as depicted above and i am still getting the same error. Do explain more if i misunderstood your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @HANYAOFOONG, I don't think you are sharing the errors. the traceback you have shared is a access log from django. I have added comments to my answer. please have a look if it makes sense.